# Question about trees, Let T be a tree with n vertices

Tags: graph-theory, trees

Are my answers correct to these 3 questions?

**Let T be a tree with n vertices.**

```
1) What is the average degree/valency of the vertices in T?
```

Average Degree of of vertices in T = 2 times total number of edges

```
2) Suppose T has a vertex of degree/valency 3. What is the smallest   
   number of leaves that T can have?
```

3 leaves

```
3)  Give an example of a tree with a vertex of degree/valency 3 
    with the smallest number of leaves.
```

Does this tree fulfill the above requirement?

```
                                  1
                                 / 
                                3                                         
                               / \
                              1   1
```

Answer (score 1):

1) What you have computed is the total degree, not the average degree.

2), 3) The example you have given has 3 leaves. If you still think the answer to 2) is 2 leaves, you should provide another example.

Comment: Oh I was looking at the Tree from top to bottom. I do not know how to draw trees better than this.

Comment: How would you get the average degree?

Comment: @Bloer By definition, a leaf is a vertex with degree equal to $1$. This might be different if you have a "rooted tree," where there is one "top" vertex designated to be the root. Which context are you working in?

Comment: The question just says Let T be a tree with n vertices. But yes I have seen trees without roots

Comment: @Bloer Then the tree you drew for 3) has 3 leaves.